# Image Button does a Complete post-back on every click.

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, imagebutton

Is there anyway i can prevent a ImageButton control to avoid complete post back at the same time trying to fetch the some information on button click ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Literal ID="litRowStart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <td  >
                 <ul>
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%#String.Format(Eval("Image_Location")+".jpg") %>' CssClass="thumbnail"  ToolTip = '<%# Eval("Team_Name")%>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text='<%# Eval("serno")%>' Visible="false"/>
                     </ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
                     </ul>
                 </td>                 
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

                <asp:Literal ID="litRowEnd" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On the backend i am doing :

```
 Label1.Text = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Team_Id")).Text;
```

But every time I Click the image button it does a  post back instead of a Asynchronous one.
There is a lot of data on the page which is depending on the Serno.
Can someone please suggest me a solution or an alternative to Image Button which will perform the same functionality with a button click.
Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code that can detect which control did post back and correct your code:

```
string ctrlName = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName))
     ctrl = FindControl(ctrlName);
if (IsPostBack && ctrl!=ImageButton2)
  {
    //your code that will execute in postback    
  }
```

Comment: well i have only ImageButton on a single test page..its still does a postback..with updatepannel etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Can you make sure you have no js error and HTML is valid on the page?

Comment: I dont have any js file on the page..Its still continues to cause me a headache.